# Image Upload using selenium webdriver on mac OS

Tags: java, macos, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, image-upload

Here is my scenario :

```
1) Clicking on button where pop up comes 
2) On click of choose file image button , file upload should come 
3) After choosing image , another window comes where crop button will be there . On click , it will get uploaded automatically .
```

Please help me out for this ..

**I have tried with all possibility ways using robot / action class .**

Thankyou

Comment: Where you got stuck? any code snippet

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use sendKeys(), and from you post I assume that You cannot, you have several options. You can use robot class, but it seems that it is not working for you. Also you can do easy shortcut by calling sikuli from java - [sikuli](http://www.sikulix.com/) is framework that can interact with every element on screen by searching images. It seems it will be perfect for you.

http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html

Here you can find how to integrate sikuli with java.

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;

public class TestSikuli {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Screen s = new Screen();
            try{
                    s.click("imgs/spotlight.png", 0);
                    s.wait("imgs/spotlight-input.png");
                    s.type(null, "hello world\n", 0);
            }
            catch(FindFailed e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

"img.pdf" is path to your screenshot. You can than click on this file, drag and drop it etc. It may not be as reliable as WebDriver script, but robot class is also not reliable, and sometimes we have to take shortcuts.

Comment: I tried with Sikuli .. It did work perfectly but took time to understand the installation process . Thank you for your help :)